# HowTo Test JAX-RS Application that uses Infinispan (JBoss 7 + Arquillian)

Tags: exception, dependency-injection, jboss7.x, jboss-arquillian, infinispan

**Info:** My Application is a simple JAX-RS Service that stores some values in a cache provided by JBoss 7.1.

I would like to use Arquillian to call the service and test the response. But unfortunately I get this error when I try to run a test:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
Can not set org.infinispan.manager.CacheContainer field 
com.company.DataCache.container to 
org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultEmbeddedCacheManager
```

Here is my DataCache class:

```
@ManagedBean
public class DataCache<K, V> {

  @Resource(lookup="java:jboss/infinispan/container/hibernate")
  private CacheContainer container;
  private Cache<K, V> cache;

  @PostConstruct
  public void start() {
      this.cache = this.container.getCache();
  }

  public Cache<K, V> getCache() {
      return cache;
  }
}
```

My Testclass looks like that:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
@RunAsClient
public class SyncClientServerTest extends RbmlClientServerTest {

    @Deployment(testable = false)
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() {
        MavenDependencyResolver mvnResolver = DependencyResolvers.use(MavenDependencyResolver.class).loadMetadataFromPom("pom.xml").goOffline();

        return ShrinkWrap
            .create(WebArchive.class, "cache-service.war")
            .addPackages(true, Filters.exclude(".*ClientServerTest.*"), "com/company")
            .addAsLibraries(mvnResolver.artifact("org.infinispan:infinispan-core:5.2.0.Final").resolveAsFiles())
            .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

    @Test
    public void testStatus() throws Exception {
        ClientRequest request = new ClientRequest("localhost:8080/cache-service/cache");
        request.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE);
        request.body(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE, "");

        ClientResponse<String> responseObj = request.post(String.class);
        assertEquals(200, responseObj.getStatus());
    }
}
```

**Question**

- @Resource delivers the right cache from JBoss, is there a way to manipulate that like getting the Resource for a Database?
- Is there a way to Mock up Service calls like getCache()?

All in all I want to use Arquilian for Client testing because I use a lot of Dependency Injection, maybe there is an example project out there that uses @Resource and Infinispan.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After all answers I got the answer and I just want to summarize it for other who look for the same issue.

1. Removed the line: `.addAsLibraries(mvnResolver.artifact("org.infinispan:infinispan-core:5.2.0.Final").resolveAsFiles())`
2. Add a `MANIFEST.MF` File to `src/test/resource` with the content `Dependencies: org.infinispan export`
3. Add the line `.addAsManifestResource("MANIFEST.MF")` to ShrinkWrap
4. Add the following to your standalone.xml/ domain.xml profile in JBoss:

   ```
   <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0">
       <global-modules>
           <module name="org.infinispan" slot="main"/>
       </global-modules>
   </subsystem>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The cache container you're trying to plug is the 2nd level cache for Hibernate. You should not really try to get access to the underlying cache for Hibernate 2LC. If you need info about this cache, enable 2LC statistics.

If what you want to do is plug Infinispan Caches, check the [Infinispan JBoss AS7 quickstart](https://github.com/infinispan/infinispan-quickstart/tree/master/jboss-as7) in  where you can see how to define your own cache container, and plug it into your CDI application.

Comment: The major problem was a missing MANFEST.MF and that I added infinispan-core to my Deployment of Arquillian. But thanks for the hint, I'll definitely look into it.

Answer (score 1):

do you package any Infinispan classes together with your arquillian deployment? Infinispan is bundled with JBoss as module and should be availiable without deploying. Ambigious class names in classpath could cause that problem.

Regards

Jan

Comment: I think thats one part of the problem, see my answer below.